# How to create Find.Elements.By.Name(string name) in fluent API design?

Tags: c#, fluent-interface

Is this possible to create something like `Find.Elements.By.Name(string name)` using fluent api design pattern in c#? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe create an extension method for collection of Elements `Elements.FindByName`

Comment: @Fabio Thanks! I found a way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to implement this:

```
    public class Find
    {
        public struct Elements
        {
            public struct By
            {
                public static WindowsElement Name(string name)
                {
                    // code here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```